# ImageCoercion not enabled in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to insert image from addin to powerpoint slide using this function

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync
```

However, it does not work on PowerPoint 2016 whereas it works correctly on PowerPoint online. This is error message that I got

```
The enumeration isn't supported in the current host application.
```

I updated office library to latest using

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and also updated my manifest xml file

```
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
```

My PowerPoint client version is 16.0.4266.1001 64-bit in Windows 7

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide the actual call to setSelectedDataAsync() that you're making? ImageCoercion is supported by PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

that build number you have is quite old. if you want to try that API I strongly recommend you to update your office. PLease goto File->Account-> Office Update.

Once updated try again and it should work.
thx!